# What is the correct substitute for rc.local in systemd instead of re-creating rc.local

Tags: systemd, rc.local

I cannot find the correct way to execute some **local** scripts (or very local commands) at systemd, I already know I must not create a service (in systemd a unit) for this kinds of scripts (or I must?)....

The workaround that I found is to create rc.local and give to it execution permissions.

```
printf '#!/bin/bash \n\nexit 0' >/etc/rc.local 
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

For example, if I get a legacy server with a simple rc.local configured by you, I will know what did you do and how much it gonna hurt to upgrade or install something new on the distro, as rc.local was respected by external packages, but in the other hand if I install a server and create a systemd unit or two or three (or even sysvinit services), just for doing a simple task, this can sometimes make your life harder, and much more than this my units names can someday conflicts with the names of the new services created by the distribution development, and maybe installed on a upgrade, causing trouble for my scripts !

I see **another question** asking about **where is rc.local** and the answer was to create it and give execution permissions, I think my question is really **not** a **duplicate**, because I do not want to know where it is - believe me, I just want to **accept** that it is **deprecated**, but i cannot find the correct way for doing this kind of things, should I really create a unit just for some simple like that?

Comment: systemd "the only winning move is not to play"; alternatively, depending on what you want, you may create a systemd Unit. I would probably use rc.local for now, and care about it when it goes away.

Comment: When I tried Ubuntu I created an Unit for having a persistent ssh-agent caching in my desktop while I did not reboot  and another for something else I cannot remember; you can also create one pointing to /etc/rc.local but it seems the system is doing it for yourself for now....I would rc.local for the time being, and if is discontinued, create one pointing to a fake /etc/rc.local then.

Comment: This is likely to break documentations as if some book say that you must put something in /etc/rc.local, and you try to upgrade this docs, saying for example that rc.local must be marked as executable, when it becomes totally deprecated the documentation is broken, but if you say that you must create unit to point to /etc/rc.local, this brokes documentation because systemd is  conflicting with your unit.  I believe if you are right, they probably did not decided if it is deprecated or not, because they still don't have a substitute... when they decide all documentation will be broken again.

Comment: Which kind of script do you need to execute? Systemd has a lot of unit types. "Service" is only [one of many unit types](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#Concepts). E.g. Mount units, automount units, timer units, target units. Could one of them solve your problem?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As pointed out elsewhere, it becomes moderately unclean to use `rc-local.service` under `systemd`.

1. It is theoretically possible that your distribution will not enable it.  (I think this is not common, e.g. because disabling the same build option also removes `poweroff` / `reboot` commands that a lot of people use).
2. The semantics are not entirely clear.  Systemd defines `rc-local.service` one way, but Debian provides a drop-in file which alters at least one important setting.

`rc-local.service` can often work well.  If you're worried about the above, all you need to do is make your own copy of it!  Here's the magic:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/my-startup.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/my-startup-script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't think you need to understand every single detail[*], but there are two things you need to know here.

1. You need to enable this with `systemctl enable my-startup.service`.
2. If your script has a dependency on any other service, including `network-online.target`, you must declare it.  E.g. add a `[Unit]` section, with the lines `Wants=network-online.target` and `After=network-online.target`.

   You don't need to worry about dependencies on "early boot" services - specifically, services that are already ordered before `basic.target`.  Services like `my-startup.service` are automatically ordered after `basic.target`, unless they set `DefaultDependencies=no`.

   If you're not sure whether one of your dependencies is an "early boot" service, one approach is to list the services that are ordered before `basic.target`, by running `systemctl list-dependencies --after basic.target`.  (Note that's `--after`, not `--before`).

There are some considerations that I think also applied to pre-systemd `rc.local`:

1. You need to make sure your commands are not conflicting with another program that tries to control the same thing.
2. It is best not to start long-running programs aka daemons from `rc.local`.

---

[*] I used `Type=oneshot` + `RemainAfterExit=yes` because it makes more sense for most one-shot scripts.  It formalizes that you will run a series of commands, that `my-startup` will be shown as "active" once they have completed, and that you will not start a daemon.

Comment: Well, there is some kind of "local" place for creating services or snippets, or whatever - or can i trust this is local and should not be altered? if i develop my own daemons? Because i don't want to alter the originallity of the system, so when i install some apt-get i dont want to see my system on fire because of a replaced script, or something like this for example. I just want to trust the daemon will be just started only once, without doing any additional crazy things that i fear... like trying to restart it as infinite if it is broken, etc...

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini if you're asking what the right way to start a daemon is, you should really define an individual service for it.  That can be a native system `.service` unit, or if you really want to write an LSB init script you can do that instead.  I didn't want to recommend putting several daemons in `rc-local.service` or equivalent, I think it probably works, but it seems much nicer if you can restart the individual daemon with `systemctl restart my-daemon` just like anything else.  It's intended that you put your local services in `/etc/systemd/system`.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini you have to avoid using the same name as any other service - just like in sysvinit.  In similar situations I've sometimes started my names with `local-`...

Comment: How do i say in a safe way to systemd that this scripts must be start after everything no matter what system starts.  Because original rc.local, are started after all... i dont want to say what services are dependant or not just say.. after all, after everything start this. This version already do this?

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini systemd rc.local does not ensure this, and neither does my version. In practice, a lot gets covered by the `DefaultDependencies` I described (and you get a lot indirectly without saying, i.e. it waits for all filesystems to be mounted, therefore it waits for all devices which you have filesystems on). Note that if you want to wait for all hardware buses to be scanned, you need something a little special since systemd boot does not do that anywhere by default. Have a look at the documentation and the code of `systemd-udev-settle.service`.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini technically if you disable `DefaultDependencies` yourself, you can arrange to order yourself after `multi-user.target graphical.target` instead of before. But e.g. you still have to worry about the udev-settle thing.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini Note rc.local e.g. on pre-systemd Ubuntu 12.04, was not guaranteed to start "after everything" either.  Look at [how it runs rc.local](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59929/whats-the-difference-between-etc-rc-local-and-etc-init-d-rc-local).  It is an LSB init script with explicit dependencies just like a systemd service.  And when you use `startpar` on this system, LSB scripts are started in parallel where possible, very similar to systemd.

Comment: Thank you!!! Saved after half a day.  These details were critical for me: Type=oneshot, RemainAfterExit=yes, Wants=network-online.target, After=network-online.target.  Just deploying a build of apache and setting static IP to 192.168.1.80, so the router can direct traffic there.  Should be trivial.  It's annoying in Debian9.  Hardly any online advice except "apt-get apache", "systemctl start apache" or instructions with init.d, none of which apply for source-built Apache under Debian9.

Comment: @MichaelsonBritt *It is best not to start long-running programs aka daemons from rc.local. I used `Type=oneshot` ... it formalizes that ... you will not start a daemon.* If you want information about starting a daemon, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 23):

## Forget about `rc.local`.

As [I said about CentOS 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247543/5132) and [about Debian 8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333003/5132) and [about Ubuntu 15](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202743/5132):

You're using a systemd+Linux operating system.  `/etc/rc.local` is a double backwards compatibility mechanism in systemd, because it is a backwards compatibility mechanism for a mechanism that was itself a compatibility mechanism in the van Smoorenburg System 5 `rc` clone.

Using `/etc/rc.local` can go horribly wrong.  People have been surprised by the fact that systemd doesn't run `rc.local` in quite the same way, in quite the same place in the bootstrap, as they are used to.  (Or erroneously expect: It did not, in fact, run *last* in the old system, as the OpenBSD manual still points out.)  Others have been surprised by the fact that what they set up in `rc.local` expecting the old ways of doing things, is then completely undone by the likes of new `udev` rules, NetworkManager, `systemd-logind`, `systemd-resolved`, or various "Kit"s.

As exemplified by "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389289/", some operating systems already provide systemd *without* the backwards compatibility features [such as the `systemd-rc-local-generator` generator](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/044c2c7a2b322b6561d7e3cc5a48a548fee887f9/meson.build#L1912).  [Whilst Debian still retains the backwards compatibility features](https://sources.debian.org/src/systemd/239-10/debian/rules/#L48), [Arch Linux builds systemd with them turned off](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/systemd#n133).  So on Arch and operating systems like it expect `/etc/rc.local` *to be entirely ignored*.

Forget about `rc.local`.   It's not the way to go.  You have a systemd+Linux operating system.  So make a proper systemd service unit, and don't begin from a point that is two levels of backwards compatibility away.  (On Ubuntu and Fedora, it is *three* times removed, the van Smoorenburg System 5 `rc` clone that followed `rc.local` having then been *itself twice* superseded, over a decade ago, first by upstart and then by systemd.)

Also remember [the first rule for migrating to systemd](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/daemonize.html#first-rule).

This is not even a new idea that is specific to systemd.  On van Smoorenburg `rc` and Upstart systems, the thing to do was to make a proper van Smoorenburg `rc` script or Upstart job file rather than use `rc.local`.  Even FreeBSD's manual notes that nowadays one creates a proper Mewburn `rc` script instead of using `/etc/rc.local`.  Mewburn `rc` was introduced by NetBSD 1.5 in 2000.

`/etc/rc.local` dates from the time of Seventh Edition Unix and before.  It was superseded by `/etc/inittab` and a runlevel-based `rc` in AT&T Unix System 3 (with a slightly different `/etc/inittab` in AT&T Unix System 5) **in 1983**.  Even *that* is now history.

Create proper native service definitions for your service management system, whether that be a service bundle for the nosh toolset's `service-manager` and `system-control`, an `/etc/rc.d/` script for Mewburn `rc`, a service unit file for systemd, a job file for Upstart, a service directory for runit/s6/daemontools-encore, or even an `/etc/init.d/` script for van Smoorenburg `rc`.

In systemd, such administrator-added service unit files go in `/etc/systemd/system/` usually (or `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/` rarely).  With the nosh service manager, `/var/local/sv/` is a conventional place for local service bundles.  Mewburn `rc` on FreeBSD uses `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/`.  *Packaged* service unit files and service bundles, if you are making them, go in different places, though.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering et al. (2014). [*systemd-rc-local-generator*](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-rc-local-generator.html). systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- [`rc.local`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.local&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports).  *FreeBSD System Manager's Manual*.  2016-04-23.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132
- Lennart Poettering (2011-08-29). *[Plese remove `/etc/rc.local` or `chmod -x` it](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=734268)*.  Redhat bug #734268.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211927/5132
- Dirk Schmitt (2017-12-19). *[`rc.local` is starting to early](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7703)*. systemd bug #7703
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Systemd&diff=378926&oldid=378924
- Benjamin Cane (2011-12-30).  *[When it's Ok and Not Ok to use `rc.local`](https://bencane.com/2011/12/30/when-its-ok-and-not-ok-to-use-rc-local/)*. bencane.com.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49636/5132
- Lennart Poettering (2010-10-01). *[How Do I Convert A SysV Init Script Into A systemd Service File?](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-3.html)*.  0pointer.de.
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/523369/
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past.*](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [*A side-by-side look at run scripts and service units.*](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/run-scripts-and-service-units-side-by-side.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). *[A real-world worked example of setting up and running a service with nosh](https://jdebp.uk/Softwares/nosh/worked-example.html)*. Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). "[Missing system search paths from the `systemd.unit` manual page](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/systemd-documentation-errata.html#MissingUsrLocalLibSystemd)". *Errata for systemd doco*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini A better question would be how to handle a specific snippet of rc.local in a systemd service. So if you have a specific snippet in mind (you mention instructions from some software's documentation), maybe post a question about that one instead? There are certain general rules that can be used for conversion, but you get more out of it by exploiting features of the software you're running (such as running in foreground, not trying to daemonize, etc.) so asking about a specific case might be helpful.

Comment: You gotta wonder if it has survived deprecation since 1983, maybe it has something going for it?

Comment: This answer is preachy and fails to actually just answer the simple "what trivial thing should I do instead" question.  It may contain information, and provide tons of references, but defeats the purpose of stackexchange.

Comment: I bring this (the end of rc.local) up, together with dns resolving issues, as reasons why linux isn't evolving, but actually getting to be spaghetti-code more and more, systemd has become a black box for many. If a user or administrator wants to put something in rc.local and no longer can, it's not helpful to force them to first do courses systemd or whatever else you preach in order to achieve the same end-result in days, instead of minutes. Of course, idiots can do stupid things with everything that works well and is easy to work with, that's never a valid argument to end it.

Comment: I just want my laptop to connect to my Bluetooth speaker on startup.

Comment: Something that has been around since 1983 and _still works_ is a feature, not a bug. Removing ancient code might seem like a good idea, but trying to figure which of the many workarounds isn't going to be a maintenance issue has eaten the last hour of my time here in 2023.

Comment: @gps I agree that the answer is preachy and non-simple, and I hate systemd, too, but today, this unfortunately *is* an important and right answer!  There just isn't a trivial thing you can do on a systemd system that's equivalent to rc.local, and it's not the purpose of stackexchange (it's not within stackexchange's power) to change that. :-(

Answer (score 7):

Summary of https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd

Create /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
[Unit]
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
 TimeoutSec=0
 StandardOutput=tty
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then:

```
sudo touch /etc/rc.local
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
sudo systemctl enable rc-local
```

Check with:

```
sudo systemctl start rc-local.service
sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
```

Comment: The systemd-provided one uses `StandardOutput=journal+console` (console is equivalent to tty in your example), which seems like it would be much more useful for troubleshooting. Also support for `SysVStartPriority=` has been removed at some point. Maybe you could comment how important `SysVStartPriority=` is, or remove it. Apart from that, it's a decent answer.

Comment: Great answer that does the job. Maybe you could add a minimal /etc/rc.local script example though.

Comment: printf '#!/bin/bash\n\nexit 0\n' > /etc/rc.local # would create one

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use cronie

Install it:
dnf install cronie

Enable it:
systemctl enable crond

Edit user file:
crontab -e

Add command (for example when rebooting):
@reboot command

Answer (score 0):

[Cron's](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) `@reboot` support for things that only need to happen "soon" after a system has rebooted rather than as part of the boot process works well as an alternative to any form of caring about what init system is used.

Caveat: It does require ISC Cron. But appears more universally installed and enabled by default than any specific init system.