# If rc.local is run as root why can't it touch a file

Tags: debian, permissions, root, touch, rc.local

I wish to execute a script every time on boot-up using `/etc/rc.local`.

My script for example is called `startscript.sh` which is stored in `/home/debian` as below. It first tries to create a file called `test.log` and then does other things.

However, I read the error on boot-up that `touch: cannot touch ‘test.log’: Permission denied`

How is this even possible if, from what I understand, `rc.local` gets run as root, therefore anything it executes should be run as root as well, and hence `test.log` should be created regardless?

`startscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch test.log
#... other stuff
```

`rc.local` snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#.. other stuff
sh /home/debian/startscript.sh
```

Comment: You can get permission denied even as root: try to write to a read-only filesystem, try to write to a special filesystem (e.g., `/proc` or `/sys`) in a not-permitted way, try to write to a network filesystem (server does permission checks, too), etc... You haven't really given us enough information to figure out which you're seeing. What is the current working directory of `startscript.sh`?

Comment: To build off of user derobert, please include what permissions your script has, as well as the permissions of the working directory of the script or where the script is being run from. Is your `/` filesystem mounted as read only? Either `touch` is being run in a filesystem that is mounted as read-only or the script is being run before the filesystem has assigned the relevant options in fstab during the boot up process. The first option is far more likely than the latter I feel.

Comment: @derobert and @Engineer999: unless the `#.. other stuff` includes any explicit `cd` commands, then the current working directory of `startscript.sh` will be `/`, and so the file it's attempting to create will be `/test.log`. When you log in, your working directory is set to be your home directory (on modern systems, most likely by the PAM session module), *but for start-up scripts, this convenience does not exist.*

Comment: @derobert The current working directory for startscript.sh is /home/debian as shown in the rc.local file snippet

Comment: @kemotep The file system is not read-only. This is why I don't understand the problem. It should create the file . I also did sudo chmod 777 /home/debian to ensure everyone has permissions and it still complains

Comment: @Engineer999 please edit your post to include that information as well as whether your file system employs an ACL. I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13722274/10256002) that includes a script to assist in debugging. Perhaps you can add that information to your post after you try it?

Comment: @Engineer999 your snipped doesn't show that. `sh /home/debian/startscript.sh` does not change the current working directory. (`cd /home/debian/` would, but just executing a script out of it does not.)

Comment: @derobert ah ok. I see what you mean. So i'm actually trying to create file test.log in the same working directory wherever rc.local is being executed? So when I just do sh /home/debian/startscript.sh , i'm not actually executing that inside /home/debian/startscript.sh. This is my problem I guess :))

Comment: @Engineer999 could well be. A simple `cd /home/debian && ./startscript.sh` would fix that. (Though do pay attention the warnings Ken Jackson has given you.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with that approach.  One, `rc.local` is executed by root, so all the files it creates will be owned by root unless you run `chown` on them.  Second, it's a security hole in that root executes code which is potentially modifiable by a user without root privilege.

A better way is to use the *@reboot* time specifier with `cron` as an unprivileged user.  If you already have a [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) file, edit it to add this line and then run the `crontab <yourcrontab>` command.  Or use the `crontab -e` command to enter this line directly.

```
@reboot /home/debian/startscript.sh
```

Note that you don't need `sh` if the script is executable because it starts with `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: Or one could write a native service definition for whatever one's service manager is, with appropriate user account settings.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471871/5132

Comment: I don't want a better way. I know Cron works ok for this. I'm just trying to understand why rc.local won't work

Answer (score 1):

If your distribution uses `systemd`, the problem might be that `/etc/rc.local` gets executed *too early*, while the root filesystem is still read-only, or while some of the other file systems are not mounted yet.

If the systemd `.service` file that runs `rc.local` has no specific order dependencies configured, `systemd` will run it as early as possible.

Run `systemctl cat rc-local.service` to see the full definition of the service that runs `rc.local`. Pay attention to any `After=` lines, and think about the earliest possible point in the system start-up process that can satisfy those. You might want to add an override file that adds an extra `After=` line or two to suit the needs of your configuration.