# Linux CentOS: run rc.local after boot

Tags: centos, init-script

I am running a CentOS (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)) instance on AWS.
I need to add to my boot sequence execution of a rc.local script.

How can I do that?
I have looked in /ect/rc.d and tried to add the script to a default using systemctl. Nothing works.

Can someone point me to a right direction?

Comment: Which CentOS version is it?

Comment: Without knowing much about CentOS I use `/etc/init.d/boot.local` on a openSUSE virtual machine, that works for me.

Comment: For several CentOS versions you should [forget about `rc.local`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471871/5132).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three methods you can use as far as I see it.

1. Using `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`:

Make sure the file is executable or `chmod u+x` it.

Add the commands / script to the end of the file.

2. Using crontab:

Run:

```
crontab -e
```

Then add a crontab line like so:

```
@reboot /your/script/here
```

3. a [Userdata script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts):

Since it's an AWS instance, you can create a shell script, upload it to s3 and configure the instance to download and run it at instance creation time.

Here's [an example of a userdata](https://github.com/geek-kb/DevopsStuff/blob/master/Scripts/aws/userdata_script_v6.sh) script I wrote.